# Get variable with space?

Tags: php, sql, get

I want to pass name in get variable. That name contain spaces. So is not working in php.

```
$facid=$row['Facultyname'];
echo "<a href=tutorials.php?$facid>" . $row['Facultyname']. "</a><p>";
```

Please help me if Faculty name =A.K. Sharma then it only send A.K.

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: see this post this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616089/php-get-variables-with-spaces-they-work-but-is-it-correct-or-ok Its been long that I have worked with PHP, but spaces works fine as far as I remember.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `$facid` and `$row['Facultyname']` in your echo statement? They're same value, could use `$facid` for both?

Answer (score 2):

[Encode the URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
echo '<a href="tutorials.php?variable_name='.urlencode($row['Facultyname']).'">' 
     . $row['Facultyname']. '</a>';
```

EDIT: 
Set a variable name for the GET.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not actually setting a variable after the `?`, you're just pasting the value. Try:

```
$facid = $row['Facultyname'];
echo "<a href='tutorials.php?facid=". urlencode($facid) ."'>". $facid ."</a>";
```