# PHP shell_exec - Is it ever safe?

Tags: php

I'm thinking about the different ways to implement a diff. It's either I can write a wdiff from scratch in PHP, or I can simply run a [`shell_exex()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) on wdiff with two files return the string, parse it's tokens and replace appropriately. I'm just worried about the safety of allowing code to be executed on the shell like I have explained. Assume all strings that would be passed to `wdiff` would be user input that cannot be trusted under any circumctance.

Now, I know I can use libraries such as FineDiff, but honestly I would rather use the UNIX native wdiff, but am worried that shell_exec will ALWAYS be vulnerable to arbitrary code injection, shell code executing, etc. Is it safe to use?

Comment: "safety of allowing code to be executed on the shell" --- you don't execute arbitrary code but a known command with 2 parameters. What you need is just to validate/sanitize paths.

Comment: You do execute arbitrary code, actually. The two arguments (the two different strings) are in theory, user input, so do you now see the issue?

Comment: I don't see the issue because they are not arbitrary strings but filesystem paths. You just check if it's a file and it's readable and you're fine, aren't you?

Comment: Well I would first have to write two files. One containing the old string, and containing the new string.

Comment: Is there a possibility of there being code (strings) sent to wdiff that would be unsafe, or is this completely beyond PHP?

Comment: it is beyond php. Php would run anything you pass. So it's your responsibility to ensure it's "safe"

Answer (score 1):

Then we shouldn't have forms on the web either because, hey, the user could do something wrong with those, too.

The point is, if you are confident enough to use escaping of strings to allow HTML forms, then you must also know what you're doing before using the command line:

Sanitizing - this is the most important issue; favor limiting the possible range of values.

Echoing - valid point here, this can be handled by `ob_start` functions

Deleting and renaming, and executing other programs - if this is a concern, you've got deeper issues because the php system user should be limited in what it can do.

But again, if you can write code to sanitize a user form, you can sanitize your input as well.

Answer (score 0):

prevent `shell_exec()` if you can.

If input is not escaped or sanitized. that could be cause problem.
eg.

```
shell_exec("wdiff params[1] params[2]");
//can be translate to
shell_exec("wdiff /file1 /file2;echo /etc/passwd");
```

Comment: Any better alternate?

Comment: Adding a proper escape to special character or limit the input with regexp ``[A-Za-z0-9]``