# How to use GET method in php for url which has %20?

Tags: php, url

I tried to use GET method in php, but the url has home%20phone as query parameter

When i tried to read it using

```
<?php echo $_GET['home%20phone']; ?>
```

it is not working..So, how to read variables like this.

thanks.

Comment: You say "home%20phone" in your description, but use `home%phone` in your code.

Comment: Do you have any answer for this, @Ondkloss

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - GET variables with spaces - they work, but is it correct or ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616089/php-get-variables-with-spaces-they-work-but-is-it-correct-or-ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `var_dump($_GET)` to see the keys the variables are mapped to.

Answer (score 3):

`%20` is a URL-encoded space character. Try this:

```
<?php echo $_GET['home phone']; ?>
```

If you're not sure what the keys in your array are, you can always use `print_r($_GET)` or `var_dump($_GET)` to see what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `urldecode()` for extracting exact value from the get method.

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

`<?php echo urldecode($_GET['home%20phone']); ?>`